# Developing Access DB to SQL?

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2010

I built a database several years ago in Access to track over 4K pieces of equipment in and out of a shop, where it was going, current status, etc. It's dying. I would like to upgrade it, but unsure if a split Access DB or a SQL Server 2008 back with Access front would be better/sufficient. I'm leaning towards the latter.
At most 35 simultaneous users, but only on rare occasions.
Would like to track (log) changes to items each time data/status changes.
Print reports, etc.
Keep it SIMPLE for users.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think you have a reasonable question in there somewhere if you could [make it specific](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 2):

How large is your database? If you expect that your database will not grow to larger than 10 GB, and you are familiar with SQL Server, then you can use [SQL Server Express Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/sql-server-editions-express). If you don't need any of the enterprise features (page/row compression, HA/DR, encryption, table partitioning, etc), it's a great way to manage smaller amounts of data...and its free!

I've never personally used a set-up with Access ADP as a front-end, but I've heard it works fine for straight-forward data management. If you have the time/resources, creating a simple web-based front end for management (or buying something out of the box that sits on SQL Server) might allow you to reduce the complexity even further.